# Next image upload to cloudinary

Tags: typescript, mongoose, cloudinary

I hope I find help here.
I'm doing a webdev bootcamp and I'm right
now on my final project.

Since Monday I'm struggling to upload
pictures (eg. Profile avatar, images for
listings).
Ideally I would use:
Next (app Router)
Cloudinary
Mongoose

https://github.com/Synav92/ugh4.git

I've managed to get the Form data into the backend and am trying to upload it to cloudinary.
The error is 'must supply api_key'
But I think I'm providing the api key right

I think the error is somewhere here:

```
 try {
const uploadedImage = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(userImageFile.path, {
  folder: "ugh4",
});
console.log("uploadedImage>>>>>>", uploadedImage);
res.status(200).json({
  message: "image uploaded succesfully",
  userImage: uploadedImage.secure_url,
});
```

} catch (error) {
console.log(`error`  , error);
}

Comment: Please provide more specific questions/issues that you're trying to resolve/get help on which can be answered. For example, which tutorial are you following, which part of the image handling have you implemented and/or what is not working, are you getting any error messages etc? At the moment, the post is too generic.

Comment: @Aleksandar Did it

Comment: How are you currently configuring the API credentials - (cloud_name, api_key and api_secret)? If it's via an environment variable, please double-check the values are accessible within your code. You could also try to hardcode the credentials in the code instead of them coming from an environment variable and see if that works. If it does, it indicates that the values from your environment variables are either not accessible or configured correctly.

Comment: I can console.log the api credentials and checked the configure for it

Comment: Below the `cloudinary.uploader.upload()` line, please add `console.log(cloudinary.config().cloud_name,"-",cloudinary.config().api_key);` and verify the SDK has the right values.
In addition, worth double-checking that the code you shared where you call Cloudinary is the code that is running and that you don't have any other place you're trying to call the API which may be throwing this error.

Comment: In addition, you could try to add the below code above the `cloudinary.uploader.upload()` line and pass the cloud name, API key and secret directly to the SDK - please verify if you supply the credentials this way if your requests goes through.

```
cloudinary.config({
 cloud_name: "",
 api_key: "",
 api_secret: ""
});
```

Comment: @Aleksandar it doesn't get logged...?

Comment: @Aleksandar I know tired to add your console.log above the line and it says undefined - undefined

Comment: Getting "undefined - undefined" output would explain it - it indicates that the SDK is not configured correctly so the error is returned. Please use the snippet (also shared below) to configure the credentials directly in the code (with the actual values) and try to send another request ``` cloudinary.config({ cloud_name: "", api_key: "", api_secret: "" }); ``` and ensure the values are logged correctly.